# Multiline EditText shrinking when focused

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-edittext, shrink

I have a multi-link postal address EditText widget which is declared as below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pat_address_input"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
    android:lines="5"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="10pt" >
</EditText>
```

In my code, I set the focus property to true and focusontouch to true, however when the EditText widget it focused the EditText shrinks to a single line box and the cursor hangs underneath the widget.[image: Pictured Below]

How can I stop this?

Comment: Why are you setting the background drawable to @null? `android:background="@null"`.

Comment: How were you able to customize the edittext style?

Comment: I wasn't, I set background to transparent and applied a style to a bitmap behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the widget was inheriting properties from a single-line edittext

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `android:lines="5"`, this all worked for me with no issues.

I am also confused as to why your text is white when your background of the field is white.

Comment: I have code in my UI thread that changes the text colour and background colour. I'll see if removing lines will work.